# What do we call the plastic that has bubbles on it?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

As a child, I used to burst the bubbles on this thing:

[image: bubbles]

What do we call this thing in English? And how can we express the action of bursting bubbles on it (I mean the verb or phrase that we can use with this thing)?

Comment: As a child? Used to burst? I didn't know one could outgrow this fun activity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called **Bubble Wrap**. Technically it should be capitalised, as it is a trademark of the Sealed Air Corporation, but it's commonly used as a generic term.

The act of bursting the bubbles is **popping** them.

There's nothing more satisfying than sitting and **popping a sheet of bubble wrap**.

Comment: Companies that make this product and don't want to be sued by Sealed Air also call it bubble pack, bubble paper, air bubble packing, bubble wrapping, or aeroplast (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_wrap).  I've never heard anyone use any of those terms though.  It's always bubble wrap.

Comment: The walking on bubble wrap crowd might beg to differ.